# Where to put flash files in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash

I've been trying to get [dewplayer](http://www.alsacreations.fr/dewplayer-en) to work in a rails app, but they tell you to upload a `.swf` and I'm not exactly sure where to put that. Is it an asset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put it into assets. That is what it is. Then modify the html they give you to look for it in the right place, which will vary depending on your setup. I use a CDN, so my assets are in the cloud and accessed through a subdomain like: assets1.example.com/assets/file-abc123.swf